Pytorch BiLSTM: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied
I know this question has been asked and answered many times but I have this issue in an unprecedented area.
class CharRNN(torch.nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embed_dim, hidden_dim):
    super(CharRNN, self).__init__()
    

    self.embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim, padding_idx=0)
    self.rnn_lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(input_size=embed_dim,
                                        hidden_size=hidden_dim,
                                        batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
        
    
    self.linear = torch.nn.Sequential(
      torch.nn.Linear(hidden_dim, hidden_dim),
      torch.nn.ReLU(),
      torch.nn.Linear(hidden_dim, vocab_size)
    )
  def forward(self, batch_x, batch_x_lens):
    batch_x = self.embedding(batch_x)

    

    batch_x = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(batch_x,
                                                          batch_x_lens.to('cpu'),
                                                          batch_first=True,
                                                          enforce_sorted=False)

    batch_x, _ = self.rnn_lstm(batch_x)

    batch_x, _ = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(batch_x,
                                                            batch_first=True)

    batch_x = self.linear(batch_x)

    return batch_x

I don't have this issue when using one-directional rnn. It only happens when I set bidirectional=True and I don't know why and how to solve it. Hope someone could help me.
